# How to browse the files on my Samsung Galaxy Discover?

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin, mtp

I just bought a [Samsung Galaxy Discover](http://www.samsung.com/ca/consumer/mobile/mobile-phones/smartphones/SGH-S730HKMBMC) and eagerly connected it to my Kubuntu machine via the included USB cable. After selecting the option to "Open with file manager", I was redirected to the URI `camera:` which consisted of a single folder:

[image]

This folder is empty.

After some further reading, it would appear that [I need to use MTP](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access) since Android 4.0 no longer offers mass storage mode. Unfortunately, following the instructions in that article did not work for me. I received the following error:

```
Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung GT P7310/P7510/N7000/I9070/I9100/I9300 Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/S3/Nexus/Note/Y.
   Found 1 device(s):
Samsung: GT P7310/P7510/N7000/I9070/I9100/I9300 Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/S3/Nexus/Note/Y (04e8:6860) @ bus 2, dev 7
Attempting to connect device
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
Error 1: Get Storage information failed.
Error 2: PTP Layer error 02fe: get_handles_recursively(): could not get object handles.
Error 2: Error 02fe: PTP: Protocol error, data expected
Listing File Information on Device with name: (NULL)
LIBMTP_Get_Storage() failed:-1
```

So, is there some alternative method or tool I can use to interact with the contents of my phone? I am using Kubuntu 12.10 64-bit on this machine.

Comment: If you look at this discussion: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=159184, installing kio-mtp should be enough. Don't have KDE installed at the moment (just plain Ubuntu 12.10 with Unity), and am still struggling with this, kio-mtp doesn't seem to be available in ubuntu 12.10...